# How to return a variable from a python function with a single parameter

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following function:

```
def test(crew):
  crew1 = crew_data['CrewEquipType1']
  crew2 = crew_data['CrewEquipType2']
  crew3 = crew_data['CrewEquipType3']
  return
test('crew1')
```

I would like to be able to use any one of the 3 variables as an argument and return the output accordingly to use as a reference later in my code. FYI, each of the variables above is a Pandas series from a DataFrame.
I can create functions without a parameter, but for reason I can't quite get the concept of how to use parameters effectively such as that above, instead I find myself writing individual functions rather then writing a single one and adding a parameter.

If someone could provide a solution to the above that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assumption**: You problem seems to be that you want to return the corresponding variable `crew1`, `crew2` or `crew3` based on your input to the function `test`.

## Some test cases based on my understanding of your problem

- `test('crew1')` should return `crew_data['CrewEquipType1']`
- `test('crew2')` should return `crew_data['CrewEquipType2']`
- `test('crew3')` should return `crew_data['CrewEquipType3']`

To accomplish this you can implement a function like this

```py
def test(crew):
    if crew=='crew1':
        return crew_data['CrewEquipType1']
    elif crew=='crew2':
        return crew_data['CrewEquipType2']
    elif crew=='crew3':
        return crew_data['CrewEquipType3']
    ...
    ... # add as many cases you would like
    ...
    else:
        # You could handle incorrect value for `crew` parameter here
```

Hope this helps!
Drop a comment if not

Comment: Absolutely spot on!